# PyQt5 with PyInstaller error, no module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am trying to bundle a python program into an application using PyInstaller on Mac OS X. I am running into an issue where when I go to run the application directly from the executable I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtWidgets
```

I have tried to import the module as a hidden import in the .spec file.. This idea didn't worked. When I run the pyinstaller command with no hooks and no imports this prints in terminal

```
22530 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
22533 WARNING:   Removing import PIL.ImageQt from module PyQt5
```

These are my import statements

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

Why is pyinstaller excluding PyQt5 from the build? How can I prevent it from doing it?

Comment: You can check if there are multiple versions of python installed on your system, and perhaps `pyinstaller` does not have the path for all the modules it needs.  You should google `pyinstaller when things go wrong` .  The documentation gives you places to look for debug information.